# Trigonometric Functions and Asymptotics

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, asymptotics

I saw the following identities being used for my Complex Variables class:

$e^{x} = 1 + x + O(x)^{2}$

$\cos(y+y') - \cos(y) = -(\sin(y))y' + O(y')^2$

$\sin(y+y') - \sin(y) = i(\cos(y))y' + O(y')^2$

Where $i$ denotes the imaginary unit. I'm not sure how the big-$O$ notation would work in these particular cases. What would it mean in this case, and how would one derive the above properties? I'm not sure where to start.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It would be $O(x^2)$, not $O(x)^2$, and similarly for the others. Technically, those are the same, but former is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one,
for small $x$,
$e^x
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}
=1+x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}
$,
so

$\begin{array}\\
|e^x-1-x|
&=|\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}|\\
&\le\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} |\frac{x^n}{n!}|\\
&=|x^2|\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} |\frac{x^{n-2}}{n!}|\\
&=|x^2|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |\frac{x^{n}}{(n+2)n!}|\\
\end{array}
$

If
$|x| \le \frac12$,
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |\frac{x^{n}}{(n+2)n!}|
\le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |\frac{1}{2^n(n+2)n!}|
< \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |\frac{1}{2^n}|
=1
$,
so
$|e^x-1-x|
\le |x^2|
= O(x^2)
$.

Note that
almost exactly the same argument
will show that,
for any $m > 0$,
as $x \to 0$,
$e^x
=\sum_{n=0}^{m} \frac{x^n}{n!}+O(x^{m+1})
$.